# SqlAlchemy IntegrityError

Tags: python, database, sqlite, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a whole bunch of data off of facebook, and add objects into the database as I process them. For likes, for example, I am just making them the ID of the person who issued the like. However, when I add more than one like I will encounter an integrity error in sqlalchemy because the primary keys are not unique.

What is the best way to handle this? Do I have to do a query every time I'm about to add a new like to the database, find out if its there, increase its count if it exists, and create a new entry if it doesn't?

Doesn't that seem like a lot of querying? What do you think is best to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you realy need to optimize it for heavy load? Probably not, having you are using SQLite. The simple solution in this case is much better:

```
class Like(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Like'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    counter = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)


o = session.merge(Like(id=1))
session.flush()  # Required when it's new record
o.counter = Like.counter+1
session.commit()
```

There is a race condition between check and insertion, but I believe it won't beat you in practice.

When you realy need to optimize it a bit or fix this race condition, there is a `INSERT OR IGNORE` in SQLite to avoid check (there are 2 separate statements are executed yet):

```
clause = Like.__table__.insert(prefixes=['OR IGNORE'],
                               values=dict(id=1, counter=0))
session.execute(clause)
o = session.merge(Like(id=1, counter=Like.counter+1))
session.commit()
```

And finally there is a way to do it in single statement using `INSERT OR REPLACE` and subselect (there are other ways to do such thing in most other databases, e.g. `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in MySQL), but I doubt it will give you noticeable performance gain:

```
old = session.query(Like.counter).filter_by(id=1).statement.as_scalar()
new = func.ifnull(old, 0) + 1
clause = Like.__table__.insert(prefixes=['OR REPLACE'],
                               values=dict(id=1, counter=new))
session.execute(clause)
```